# Datetimepicker no muestra valor de fecha por defecto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, datepicker

Necesito mostrar la fecha por defecto en todos los campos, pero al agregar la opción del plugins **minDate: new Date()** no se muestran las fechas en los campos, pero si esta el valor internamente en el campo.

**Ejemplo:**

[image: Ejemplo]

**Código:**

```js
$(function(){
  $('.date').each(function() {
      $(this).datetimepicker({
          minDate: new Date(),
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          ignoreReadonly: true,
          useCurrent: false
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>           
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `useCurrent:true` para que te muestre la fecha actual por defecto:

```js
    $(function(){
      $('.date').each(function() {
          $(this).datetimepicker({
              minDate: new Date(),
              format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
              ignoreReadonly: true,
              useCurrent: true
          });
      });
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" readonly value="2017-01-01" placeholder="Your month">
        </div>           
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `defaultDate`  no me funciono a mi. `useCurrent ` al parecer es la solucion. Excelente.

Comment: Lo tengo en mi script y he aplicado estos cambios y me muestra el primer campo vacio pero los siguientes campos con el valor

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada, funciona correctamente.

Comment: Gracias Einer por tu colaboración. :)

Comment: @Learningandsharing ¿Esta bien que se muestre `2017-08-22` en cambio del valor `2017-01-01` que le asignaste en el `value`?

Comment: La idea es mantener el valor por que son campos que van a editar una fecha